What does "overtrimmed" mean here?
This line is from Emma (2020):

Augusta: How do you like my gown? I do not know whether
it is not overtrimmed.

My teacher says it means that Augusta is unsure if the gown has
been excessively decorated. However, the dictionary defines
"overtrimmed" as "trimmed too much", with no mention of decoration.
What does "overtrimmed" mean here?

Your teacher is right. Look at the dictionary again, and you should find trim meaning to decorate (or decoration if used as a noun).

I think this question is Off Topic because OP's teacher has already given the dictionary definition: trim to decorate something by adding objects, pieces of material, etc. that make it look attractive

Could it be that, in this case, "overtrimmed" might refer to the gown being "too short"? As in another connotation of "trim" "to cut in order to refine" (something such as hair, a plant, etc)

@kos: Given the context (date of writing and the author, as well as the narrative context) I'd say there's no chance of that (otherwise plausible) interpretation applying.

@FumbleFingers I see, thanks, I'm not familiar with the book, for me at least that connotation of trim is the first that comes to mind, and for that matter I was unaware of the "to decorate" meaning altoghether...

@kos: I'm pretty sure trimming originally meant making smart / tidy (by removing "unwanted" parts). That gradually diverged into the two different emphases 1) smartening, and 2) reducing. But the roots are the same.

@Cameron,  since you have the answer in the comments above, you could withdraw the question, or (if you think it might interest others) you could add a self answer below.

Roast turkey and all the trimmings. The 'trimmings' aren't what were cut off, but the extras that embellish.

Is it evidence that the mini-skirt was not a 20th c. invention?  We will have to rewrite that history.

https://www.google.com/search?q=dress+with+trimmings+early+18th+c.&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&oq=dress+with+trimmings+early+18th+c.&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCjQ0MTY1ajBqMTWoAgiwAgE&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:edbeb3f4,vid:84KX9LYr2gk,st:20

Although you note that the source movie Emma was made in 2020, I'm sure you know that it is a period piece based Jane Austen's 1815 novel.
In modern English, the adjective 'trimmed' most often means cut back - derived from the past tense of the verb to trim. For example, a haircut which just neatens a style without taking too much off is often called "a trim". However, we still actively use the noun 'trim' to refer to decoration around the edge of something including clothing. Although we don't use this adjective often today, in the context of your example, "trimmed" means decorated. "Overtrimmed" would mean that it i
was excessively decorative.

Like many English words, the word "trim" has multiple definitions. It can mean to "cut back", like, "She had her hair trimmed" or "I trimmed the lawn". It can also mean to "decorate", like, "We trimmed the Christmas tree".
I think you realize that adding the prefix "over-" means too much. So if you said, "He overtrimmed the lawn", that would mean he cut it too much. If I said, "He overtrimmed the Christmas tree", that would mean he put on too many decorations.
Talking about a gown, I would generally assume that "trimmed" meant "decorated". I suppose a gown could be trimmed in the sense of being cut, like if she said she "trimmed the hemline to make it shorter". But that meaning doesn't seem to apply here.
When a word has multiple definitions, you have to read the context and use some common sense to figure out which is meant. Usually it's obvious, but not always. Some jokes derive their humor from this kind of ambiguity.

And absent the context in which the character spoke that sentence, one cannot be certain which meaning (decorated or cut) was meant. I am not motivated to fetch my copy of Austen, and questions should provide enough context to allow answering.
